# What Security Suite to choose?

Tags: security, anti-virus, spam

What security suite would you recommend in an environment consisting of roughly 120 PC's and some 30 servers? Environment is MS only, so Exchange and ISA must also be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Having been a huge proponent of Symantec Enterprise products in the past, we recently dumped them in favor of ESET and their NOD32 line.

The Symantec Enterprise products suffered the same bloatware syndrome that their consumer product line has with the latest iteration and it bogged our machines down.  No longer is it Symantec Antivirus, but rather, Symantec Endpoint Protection.

I've found the NOD32 clients to be extremely fast and have a smaller footprint then their Symantec counterparts.  Having said this, the Administrators console can be a bit daunting compared to Symantec's, but once you get used to it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Avast](http://www.avast.com).  The Enterprise version is a bit expensive, but many folks enjoy the personal protection it offers and the Enterprise version is no slacker either (and it supports 64bit environments too!.

Comment: Just confirmed that Avast Enterprise does support ISA

Answer (score 0):

I've had some great experiences with NOD32.

Answer (score 0):

Symantec Endpoint Protection has been working very well for us since they released version 11.  Management of each client and group was easy to work with and the Exchange software seems to be working well, too.  When I compared prices to ESET (NOD32), they were actually a little less per license.

Answer (score 0):

[Sunbelt Software](http://www.sunbeltsoftware.com)'s VIPRE Enterprise is relatively easy to manage from the administrator side, and end-users find the client unobtrusive.